Submitting a New Form; Blank Field Value sare Getting Replaced with the Previous Record
I have an app that includes a form. When I create a new form and submit it, fields that are left blank are replaced with values from the last submitted record.
Why would it replace values from another record? Thoughts on what could be causing it?
All formulas seem to run correctly, just can't come up with what to troubleshoot.

I think I have it working with Blank() for the item property. Thank you!

As i recall, there is a caching issue with Power Apps, when sometimes opening/editing new/existing items in Forms. Have you tried resetting your form with the ResetForm(SharePointForm1) method? Or you can set the Item to Blank() if the mode is New. You can set a helper variable in the OnView, OnNew and OnEdit methods.

When you say to ResetForm, would I couple that with the NewForm button? Or when I submit the form?

I would couple it with the NewForm Button. Are you using SharePoint "Canvas App" Forms or a standalone App?

It's a Canvas App

I tried the ResestForm and it still populates unfilled cells with data from the previous record.

Can you try setting the Item Property for the new form to blank()?
